# How to remove button border style?

Tags: button, styles, autohotkey

In autohotkey, how do you remove the black button border?  I just want a button without any border on it.

I've tried all these style modifiers to no avail.

```
gui, add, button, hwndMyButton
Control, Style, -0x0,,   ahk_id %MyButton%     ;remove BS_PUSHBUTTON
Control, Style, -0x1,,   ahk_id %MyButton%     ;remove BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON
Control, Style, +0x8000,,ahk_id %MyButton%     ;add BS_FLAT
Control, Style, +0x40,,  ahk_id %MyButton%     ;add BS_ICON
```

Comment: If none of that works... You might as well use an Image button... :p

Comment: Thanks, JoeDF.  I am quite honoured by your presence.

Comment: @JoeDF How do I make an "image" button?  Just use a `picture` control?

Comment: Thanks :) I will post an answer using an "image button".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JoeDF has a nice example, but I didn't want to add such a big library (it does waaay more than I needed.

So, I just used a picture control.

```
gui, add, picture h16 w16 vMyButton gMyProcedure, icon0, mydll
```

And then I wrote up a teeny [library called Mousey](http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=8352&p=48052#p48052) that will change the cursor into a hand so the user knows it is a button when the mouse passes over it. And it is easy to make the icon change when you click on it - so you can use this procedure to show "pressed" and "unpressed" states.

The effect is that I now have a nice little icon for a "button".

```
;http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?p=48057#p48057
#SingleInstance, On
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1
#include mousey.ahk

toggle := 0
gui, add, picture, h32 vIconButton hwndIconButton gtoggleicon icon45, shell32.dll
mouseycursor := mousey_init(IconButton,"hand")
gui, show
return

toggleicon:
    if(toggle){
        guicontrol,,IconButton, *icon45 shell32.dll
        toggle := 0
    }else{
        guicontrol,,IconButton, *icon28 shell32.dll
        toggle := 1
    }
return

guiclose:
    mousey_close(mouseycursor)
    exitapp
```

Comment: Glad you found your solution ;)

Comment: I appreciate your time, JoeDF; I know any answer you post is a good one, even if it's not quite the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use images to fully customize your GUI. In our case, it's the buttons.

## [Class] ImageButton

Image Buttons for AHK GUIs.

Source: https://github.com/AHK-just-me/Class_ImageButton
Forum topic: http://ahkscript.org/boards/viewtopic.php?t=1103
An example is provided here: https://github.com/AHK-just-me/Class_ImageButton/blob/master/Sources/Sample.ahk

---

### Shortened example

```
#NoEnv
SetBatchLines, -1
#Include Class_ImageButton.ahk
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gui, DummyGUI:Add, Pic, hwndHPIC, PIC1.jpg
SendMessage, 0x0173, 0, 0, , ahk_id %HPIC% ; STM_GETIMAGE
HPIC1 := ErrorLevel
GuiColor := "Blue"
Gui, Margin, 50, 20
Gui, Font, s10
Gui, Color, %GuiColor%
ImageButton.SetGuiColor(GuiColor)
Gui, Add, Button, vBT1 w200 hwndHBT1, Button 1`nLine 2
Opt1 := [0, 0x80CF0000, , "White", "H", , "Red", 4]         ; normal flat background & text color
Opt2 := [ , "Red"]                                          ; hot flat background color
Opt5 := [ , , ,"Gray"]                                      ; defaulted text color -> animation
If !ImageButton.Create(HBT1, Opt1, Opt2, , , Opt5)
   MsgBox, 0, ImageButton Error Btn1, % ImageButton.LastError
Gui, Show, , Image Buttons
Return
; ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GuiClose:
GuiEscape:
ExitApp
```